# Dynamic Folder Creation

Tags: java, jsp

i want to make absolute path for register users

for example website url is www.icare.com

when a user register himself with user name like "Myname" a dynamic folder will create and

absolute path  for that user will be like www.icare.come/Myname. . .  and a dummy index page

will create, any one can help me...

Comment: Maybe good place to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_development

Comment: its not good to do this, instead you can have single index page for every user

Comment: i have a standard index page for all users but i wish to redirect register user to their specific clinic. form there they can login to there clinic.

Comment: you can still have one separate page for all registered users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create folders on web root. They will all get lost whenever you redeploy the webapp.

Just store all data in a DB, create a common JSP file for all users which displays the data from the DB dynamically, create a servlet which is mapped on `/*` and does roughly the following job:

```
String username = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);
User user = userDAO.find(username);

if (user != null) {
   request.setAttribute("user", user);
   request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/userindex.jsp").forward(request, response);
} else {
   // Show "unknown user" error page or whatever.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.io.File" %>
<%
 File dir = new File("Your Path to create directory");
 if (dir.exists()) 
   {
      if (dir.isDirectory()) {
           // path exists and is a directory
    }
      else {
           // path does exist but is not a directory -- probably just a file
      }
 }
 else {
      // path does not exist so create directory
      if (dir.mkdir()) {
           // directory creation successful
      }
      else {
           // directory creation unsuccessful
      }
 }
%>
```